# Disabling 'Submit' Button (while Processing on Server) without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have an old legacy Web app where I can't add jQuery.

When a form is submitted, a long server-side action takes place, and I need to disable 'Submit' until the response is rendered, or maybe the change the cursor.

I found a solution here which shows the Loading banner on Submit,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30906566/1005607

**but it doesn't remove it when the page is rendered.** There is a Forward action from my Struts Action class. How would I remove the banner once it's finished?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLoading(e) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'loading_bar.GIF';
        div.innerHTML = "Loading...<br />";
        div.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 5%; left: 40%; z-index: 5000; width: 422px; text-align: center; background: #EDDBB0; border: 1px solid #000';
        div.appendChild(img);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        return true;
        // These 2 lines cancel form submission, so only use if needed.
        //window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        //e.stopPropagation();
    }
</script>

<form  onsubmit="ShowLoading()">
</form>
```

Comment: So what exactly does your form do? Do you do an actual form submit or an ajax call? If you do a form submit the whole page will reload and the banner will disappear anyways?

Comment: It's a Form Submit to a server-side action (e.g. Struts).

Comment: You need to call JavaScript function to stop or hide the banner. In asp.net you can do it using clientscript.registerstartupscript or response.write

Answer (score 0):

Target your button and set its disabled attribute to true.

`document.querySelector("button").setAttribute('disabled', true);`

I usually refer to this website when I need to make a change that isn't enough to require me to use jQuery.
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

with out too much context, It would be somewhat difficult to say where to call another script, but I certainly can help with a script to remove your div. first you will want an ID on the div, so you can modify your hide script to have this:

```
div.id = "loadingMsg";
```

and else where you can have another script

```
function hideLoading()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("loadingMsg");
    div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
}
```

now you only have to find the correct place to call this.

you may also consider hiding and showing your submit button, like so (assuming that `submitButton` is your button)

```
submitButton.style.visibility = "hidden";

submitButton.style.visibility = "visible";
```