# How to show busy indicator without jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, busyindicator

I am using ASP.NET Core application. Lets say I have following form

```
<form asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="RegisterAddress" method="post">
    Email:  <input asp-for="Email" /> <br />
    Password: <input asp-for="Password" /><br />
    Address: <input asp-for="Address.AddressLine1" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

I want to show busy indicator when user clicks submit button. I know how to do it using JQuery and Ajax. If i use jQuery's ajax method to POST data then i dont need `asp-controller`,`asp-action` attribute on the form. But i would like to have everything defined in HTML. Instead of having partial POST logic in javascript.

So is there anyway to show busy indicator **WITHOUT** using JQuery + Ajax?

Comment: No offense, but you have the weirdest requirements. In theory it may be possible to have a middleware on the action which sends/flushes a partial rendered HTML content to which shows a animated progress bar and once finished write/flush the rest of the html content which hides the progress bar, this seem way overkill and is magnitudes of more compilcated and harder to maintain  than a few lines of javascript. That's what it was made for. It just doesn't justify the effort

Comment: @Tseng This is not a requirement. The requirement is to show busy indicator. How we show it is upto developer. And im just curious to know if we can do it without using jquery :)

Comment: So you just want it to show the spinner / indicator after post before the next page loads but don't want to post via ajax, correct?  If so, see this related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026323/show-loading-gif-after-clicking-form-submit-using-jquery