# Loading GIF after submitting form in jQuery in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to send an email after submitting a form in Laravel. For complete the send mail process Laravel needs sometimes(5-10 seconds). In that duration (5-10 seconds) I want to show a loader gif. While the mail is send the gif will disappear and a successful message will show.

**Here is my form**

```
<div class="book-appointment">

        <img src="images/loader.gif" id="gif" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; visibility: hidden;">

        <h2>Make an appointment</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post" style="margin-top: 3rem;">
            <div class="left-agileits-w3layouts same">
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Patient Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="Patient Name" placeholder="" required=""/>
                </div>  
                <div class="gaps">  
                    <p>Phone Number</p>
                    <input type="text" name="Number" placeholder="" required=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="" required="" />
                </div>
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Age</p>
                    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-agileinfo same">
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Select Date</p>      
                    <input  id="datepicker1" name="Text" type="text" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                        this.value = 'yy/mm/dd';}" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Time</p>     
                    <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="Time" class="timepicker form-control" value="">    
                </div>
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Department</p>   
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Cardiology</option>
                        <option>Ophthalmology</option>
                        <option>Neurology</option>
                        <option>Psychology</option>
                        <option>Dermatology</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="gaps">
                    <p>Gender</p>   
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Make an appointment">
        </form>
    </div>
```

My script

```
$('#add').click(function(event){

        $('#gif').css('visibility', 'visible');

        var patient_name = $('#patient_name').val();
        var patient_number = $('#patient_number').val();
        var patient_email = $('#patient_email').val();
        var patient_age = $('#patient_age').val();
        var patient_gender = $('#patient_gender').find(":selected").val();
        var service_id = $('#service_id_search').find(":selected").val();
        var schedule_time_id = $('#schedule_time_id').find(":selected").val();
        var date = $('#datepicker1').val();

        if(patient_name == '' || patient_number == '' || patient_email == '' || patient_age == '' || patient_gender == '' || service_id == '' || schedule_time_id == '' || date == '')
        {
            alert('Empty input field exist');
        }

        else if(isNaN(patient_number))
        {
            alert('Please insert numbers in Patient Number field');
        }

        else if(isNaN(patient_age))
        {
            alert('Please insert numbers in Age field');
        }

        else
        {
            $.get( 'confirm_appointment', {'patient_name': patient_name, 'patient_number': patient_number, 'patient_email': patient_email, 'patient_age': patient_age, 'patient_gender': patient_gender, 'service_id': service_id, 'schedule_time_id': schedule_time_id, 'date': date, '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()}, function( data )
            {

                // console.log(data);

                $('#exampleModal .bg-agile .book-appointment h2').remove();
                $('#exampleModal .bg-agile .book-appointment form').remove();

                trHTML = '';

                if(data > 0)
                {                       
                    trHTML += "<h2> Your appointment is successfully submitted </h2>";
                }
                else
                {
                    trHTML += "<h2> No </h2>";
                }

                trHTML += "<center><a href='/'><button class='btn btn-secondary btn-lg' style='padding: 16px 20px 20px 20px; color: #fff; margin-top:20px;'>Go Back to Homepage</button></a></center>";

                $('#exampleModal .bg-agile .book-appointment').append(trHTML);

                // console.log(data);
                // $("#report").load(location.href + " #report");

            });
        }



    });
```

I have already see this article [[Show loading gif after clicking form submit using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026323/show-loading-gif-after-clicking-form-submit-using-jquery]) but not working...

Anybody help please ?

Answer (score 2):

Showing a div while sending an ajax request, You can use `ajaxStop()` and `ajaxStart()` together. here is an example.

```
var $loading = $('#yourloadingdiv').hide();
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
  $loading.show();
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
 $loading.hide();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @raff I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

you could use in this way

```
//start actions

$('#your-loader').show();

$.post(endpoint, options, function(response){
  $('#your-loader').hide();
}).fail(function(){
  $('#your-loader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add id both `form` and `image`.
Now inside javascript `$('#add').click(function(event){})` function do the following

```
$('#appointment-form').hide();
$('#gif').show();
```

While successfully send the mail, just hide the `gif` id lnside the ajax

`$('#gif').hide();`

Here is my full code

```
$('#add').click(function(event){

        $('#appointment-form').hide();
        $('#gif').css('margin-top','80px');
        $('#gif').show();

        var patient_name = $('#patient_name').val();
        var patient_number = $('#patient_number').val();
        var patient_email = $('#patient_email').val();
        var patient_age = $('#patient_age').val();
        var patient_gender = $('#patient_gender').find(":selected").val();
        var service_id = $('#service_id_search').find(":selected").val();
        var schedule_time_id = $('#schedule_time_id').find(":selected").val();
        var date = $('#datepicker1').val();

        if(patient_name == '' || patient_number == '' || patient_email == '' || patient_age == '' || patient_gender == '' || service_id == '' || schedule_time_id == '' || date == '')
        {
            alert('Empty input field exist');
        }

        else if(isNaN(patient_number))
        {
            alert('Please insert numbers in Patient Number field');
        }

        else if(isNaN(patient_age))
        {
            alert('Please insert numbers in Age field');
        }

        else
        {

            $.get( 'confirm_appointment', {'patient_name': patient_name, 'patient_number': patient_number, 'patient_email': patient_email, 'patient_age': patient_age, 'patient_gender': patient_gender, 'service_id': service_id, 'schedule_time_id': schedule_time_id, 'date': date, '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()}, function( data )
            {

                $('#exampleModal .bg-agile .book-appointment h2').remove();
                $('#exampleModal .bg-agile .book-appointment form').remove();

                trHTML = '';

                if(data > 0)
                {                       
                    trHTML += "<h2 style:'margin-top'> Your appointment is successfully submitted </h2>";
                }
                else
                {
                    trHTML += "<h2> No </h2>";
                }

                trHTML += "<center><a href='/'><button class='btn btn-secondary btn-lg' style='padding: 16px 20px 20px 20px; color: #fff; margin-top:20px;'>Go Back to Homepage</button></a></center>";

                $('#gif').hide();
                $('#exampleModal .bg-agile .book-appointment').append(trHTML);


            });
        }



    });
```